# JSF: Binding two values from the same form field

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I am setting a value in the login-bean when the user logs-in 
using

--**Login-bean**

```java
 setMailNickname(mailnickname);
```

And in the info page I am able to retrieve the same value using

--**InfoPage**

```xhtml
 <h:inputText value="#{login.mailNickname}" />
```

Now on the info page I am taking some more info from the user and saving all of them in the database, As one of the value is from the login form bean it is prepopulating on the Info-page but how to assign the same value to the info-page bean variable-

```
InfoBean.mailNickname
```

so that it can be saved into the database with the other fields which the user provides.
How can I assign the value to the infopage bean variable?

Comment: I suppose you've got a `@SessionScoped` managed bean (`login`) which stores the logged user info and you need to display a view with all of that in order to be able to edit it. Your question, however, lacks that info, also the JSF implementation version being used. Please narrow it.

Comment: By the way, I do not think this question is related to Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject LoginBean into InfoBean, so that you can have a reference to its fields. As I understand one of your beans is at least @SessionScoped. You didn't provide that information, so I'd go as far as to guess that LoginBean is used for logging into your application or something like that and InfoBean to hold that information for future reference. Following that chain of thinking your InfoBean would look like that:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class InfoBean {

    private String mailNickname;

    public String getMailNickname() {
        return mailNickname;
    }

    public void setMailNickname(final String mailNickname) {
        this.mailNickname = mailNickname;
     }    

     // other fields, methods...
}
```

and your LoginBean then would hold reference to session-scoped InfoBean:

```
   @ManagedBean
   @ViewScoped
   public class LoginBean {

       private String mailNickname;

       public String getMailNickname() {
          return mailNickname;
       }

       public void setMailNickname(final String mailNickname) {
           this.mailNickname = mailNickname;
       }

       @ManagedProperty("#{infoBean}")
       private InfoBean infoBean;

       public void setInfoBean(final InfoBean infoBean) {
           this.infoBean = infoBean;
       }

       /** Method you use for populating */
       public void populateInput(final String mailNicknameFromDb) {
         setMailNickname(mailNicknameFromDb);
         infoBean.setMailNickname(mailNicknameFromDb);
       }
   }
```

Remember about getters and setters for those fields as well as setter for managedProperty and be careful about scopes (you can't for example inject request-scoped bean into application-scoped bean, because the request-scoped one would probably not exist yet when creating application-scoped one).

Comment: So you want to set it programatically in the backing bean when populating the values? Then the way with managed property is your best bet I think. I will modify the answer to show you what I mean, although it has some requirements on the scope.